# Ubuntu 20.04-desktop wired connected but unable to access the Internet

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet, wired

As mentioned in the title, my machine is Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, and the wired network is connected, but I can only ping the local area network and cannot access the internet:

[image: screenshot]

There is no problem with `ifconfig` displaying the network card. The following image is the result of `service NetworkManager status`:

[image: image here]

It shows `NetworkManager` state is now `CONNECTED_LOCAL` and `CONNECTED_SITE`, but I think the correct state should be `CONNECTED_GLOBAL`.

And here are some other information about configuration:

- The result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

  [image: image here]
- Information in `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

  ```
  iface ens18 inet static
  address 192.168.0.7
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  metric 103
  ```
- Information in `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

  ```
  [main]
  plugins=ifupdown, keyfile
  [ifupdown]
  managed=true
  [device]
  wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
  ```
- Information in `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-ubuntu-fan.conf`:

  ```
  [keyfile]
  unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
  ```

I am not sure what the cause of the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't use screenshots for the outputs of terminal commands, as they are hard to read and cannot be copy-pasted by other users to assist you. Instead of screenshots, copy and paste the command outputs and format them as code. See here for more information about text formatting: [Markdown Editing Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Thanks, I will pay attention next time!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the problem. This is a machine created on the school server, and the source of the problem is that the administrator made an error in allocating network resources